# Populating ComboBox dynamically in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to populate a ComboBox dynamically in dojo. I have declared it in html and I am trying to created the Memory store in js and then setting the store attribute for the ComboBox with that value of store which I am creating in js. Here are my html and javascript files. I am calling a function in js which get a json response(*item*) as its argument and in that response values are coming(*ResultData1,ResultData2,ResultData3*) I have tested that by keeping alert boxes. But when running this page i am getting **TypeError: Memory is not a constructor** error. Can someone please explain me what i am doing wrong.

FYI: I have added all the required dependency list in my js file.

HTML:

```
<select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" data-dojo-attach-point="importDocumentTo" id="importDocumentTo" name="importDocumentTo">
```

JavaScript:

```
_onPopulate : function(item) {
                 alert('_onPopulate:');            
                 var combo = dijit.byId('importDocumentTo');
                 alert('combo' + combo)

                 var stateStore=new Memory({
                       data: [
                              {name:item["ResultData1"], id:"data1"},
                              {name:item["ResultData2"], id:"data2"},
                              {name:item["ResultData3"], id:"data3"}
                              ]      
                 });

                 alert('stateStore:' + stateStore);

          var result=domAttr.set("importDocumentTo","store",stateStore);
```

Comment: The details provided are not sufficient. Are you creating a template based widget? can you provide more code to clarify your issue.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a DOM API to update the store on a widget is not going to work.  Instead of using `domAttr.set` to set the store, you should be referencing the widget itself and calling `set('store', ...)` on the widget.

Moreover, there should be no need for a static `id` on the widget in your template, since you are already assigning it an attach point.  Assigning it a static `id` makes it impossible to create more than one instance of the widget at a time, because the static ID would conflict between instances.

You should be able to solve your problem with the following changes:

1. Remove the static `id="..."` from the element in the template
2. Replace `var combo = dijit.byId('importDocumentTo')` with `var combo = this.importDocumentTo` (to reference the attach point rather than the ID)
3. Replace `domAttr.set("importDocumentTo", ...)` with `combo.set('store', stateStore)`