# How can I create dojo combobox dropdown

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, treeview

I created dojo div element for a dojo combo box . Now I want to create a tree like structure to choose drop down value. I want to attach tree object in div element through java script file using read or write store (dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore).....

I am trying the below html and js files for it but I am getting the below error message. **no such method dom.byId**

div element for combo box :

```
<div>
<tr>
<td><label for="fixedSubCategory">Fixed SubCategory</label></td>
<td><select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"
id="fixedSubCategory" name="fixedSubCategory" value="">             
</select></td>
</tr>
```

JS file to attach tree object :

```
var displayData ={
"identifier":"id",
"label":"name",
"items":[
{
    "type": "parent",
        "name": "Countries",
        "id": "countries",
        "children":[
        {"type":"Leaf", "name":"Country 1", "id":"country1"},
        {"type":"Leaf", "name":"Country 2", "id":"country2"},
        {"type":"Leaf", "name":"Country 3", "id":"country3"},
        {"type":"Leaf", "name":"Country 4", "id":"country4"},
        {"type":"Leaf", "name":"Country 5", "id":"country5"},
        {"type":"Leaf", "name":"Country 6", "id":"country6"}
    ]
    }]}

    var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: displayData });

    var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
    store: store1,
    query: {"type": "parent"},
            rootId: "root",
            rootLabel: "Groups",
            childrenAttrs: ["children"]
        });

        var treeObject = new dijit.Tree({
            model: treeModel
        }, "treeDiv")

        if (dijit.byId("fixedSubCategory") != null) {

                dom.byId("fixedSubCategory").appendChild(treeObject.domNode);
                treeObject.startup();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `dom.byId()` and such is seen in the context of a proper AMD module, e.g.:

```
define([ 'dojo/dom', ... ], function (dom, ...) {
    // do something with dom.byId
});
```

If you are writing modules in AMD format (which is heavily encouraged), make sure you are actually including the `dojo/dom` module in your dependencies list and assigning the module to the `dom` argument in your factory function (if you think you are already doing this, then make sure the dependencies array and function argument order match up).  Then it should work fine.

(Also, the appropriate way to reference `dijit.byId` would be via the `dijit/registry` module, rather than the `dijit` global.)

On the other hand, it looks like most of your other code isn't really making use of the AMD format at all (e.g. `dojo.data`, `dijit.tree`, etc.).  While it'd be recommended to update to the AMD format (and it seemed like you had been using it in [Populating ComboBox dynamically in dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31021644/237950) with `domAttr`), the non-AMD,  global equivalent to `dom.byId` is `dojo.byId`.

Comment: I have included all the required dependencies list, sorry forgot to mention before. But still its giving me error. Is there any good example link which you can provide for the same. As i have seen many examples and nothing seems to be working. Also I have tried dijit by Id as well that also didn't work

Comment: The only way to help you is to post the full code, we can't help you fix what we can't see

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a combobox, i guess.

We managed it like this :
"results" is the result of a query on our street-shape-file.

```
function streetsToCombobox(results){

    var adress;
    var values = [];
    var testVals={};

    var features = results.features;

    require(["dojo/_base/array","dojo/store/Memory","dijit/form/ComboBox"],    
    function(array,Memory,Combobox){        
       if (!features[0]) {
          alert(noDataFound);
       }
    else {
        array.forEach(features, function(feature, i){
            adress = feature.attributes.STRASSE;

 //Check for doublefeatures
            if (!testVals[adress]) {
                testVals[adress] = true;
                values.push({
                    name: adress
                });
            }

        });
        values.sort(SortByName);

        var dataItems = {
            identifier: 'name',
            label: 'name',
            items: values
        };

            storeStreet = new Memory({
                data: dataItems
            });

    }
var comboBox = new ComboBox({
    id: "MyCB",
    name: "street",
    value: "",
    store: storeStreet ,
    searchAttr: "name"
},"DomeNodeForBox");

});
}
```

For all further Infos have a close look into the Documentation : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#dijit-form-combobox